# Отцентровка и дубляж окна tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

Использую заставку для основного окна в приложении написаного на основе tkinter на пайтоне. Как не нстроивал окно заставки, не могу добиться идеала. Задача чтобы окно затавки повторяло основное окно по размеру и чтобы оба появлялись в центре екрана.

Основное окно:

```py
root = Tk()
    root.title('Covid-19 Magic8Ball')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    canvas = Canvas(root, height= 500, width= 610)
    canvas.pack()
```

Окно заставки:

```py
splash_root = Tk()
splash_root.title("opa")

splash_root.geometry("500x500")
windowWidth = splash_root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = splash_root.winfo_reqheight()
print("Width",windowWidth,"Height",windowHeight)
 
# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(splash_root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(splash_root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
 
# Positions the window in the center of the page.
splash_root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

splas_label = Label(splash_root, text = "Slash")
splas_label.pack(pady=20)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

def center_window(window, parent=None):
    window.update_idletasks()
    width  = window.winfo_width()
    height = window.winfo_height()
    if parent is None:    # центрируем относительно экрана
        x = (window.winfo_vrootwidth()  - width ) // 2
        y = (window.winfo_vrootheight() - height) // 2
    else:     # центрируем относительно родительского окна
        window.wm_transient(parent.winfo_toplevel())
        window.lift()
        x = parent.winfo_rootx() + (parent.winfo_width()  - width ) // 2
        y = parent.winfo_rooty() + (parent.winfo_height() - height) // 2
    window.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

def show_splash(parent):
    splash_root = Toplevel()
    splash_root.title("opa")
    #splash_root.geometry("500x500")
    splash_root.geometry(f"{parent.winfo_width()}x{parent.winfo_height()}")
    splash_root.overrideredirect(True)
    splash_label = Label(splash_root, text = "Splash", bg="#ffa0a0")
    splash_label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    center_window(splash_root, parent)
    splash_root.after(2000, lambda: splash_root.destroy()) # автоубирание splash через 2 секунды

root = Tk()
root.title('Covid-19 Magic8Ball')
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = Canvas(root, height= 500, width= 610)
canvas.pack()

center_window(root)
show_splash(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: При запуске программы основное окно (уже интерпретированное из моего проекта) отображается вне центральной области экрана, а уже затем происходит заставка и показ централизованного центрального окна.

Comment: можно ли установить задержку на основное окно так как после компиляции бликом проскакивает основное а затем уже идет заставка?

Comment: @decadent В каком смысле задержка? Отрисовать основное окно, а потом с задержкой заставку?